# Pygame keeps giving me 'pygame.error: Couldn't open .png' even with using relative path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, png

I'm having trouble opening a png in pygame.
I found other ones which recommend using a relative path, but it's still not working.
Is there something else I can try?

I'm using Python 3.7.9

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import os


current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
resource_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'resources')
image_path = os.path.join(resource_path, 'images')

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')
icon = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'ufo.png'))
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True

# Game Loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Here is the Error message:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Github\PyGame Lessons\Space Invader\venv\main.py", line 15, in <module>
   icon = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'ufo.png'))
pygame.error: Couldn't open D:\Github\PyGame Lessons\Space Invader\venv\resources\images\ufo.png
```

Comment: Could the file be corrupted? Can you open `ufo.png` in an image viewer ok?

Comment: @Kingsley Yes I could open it in other image viewers.

Comment: Are you *110% sure* this image is actually in the path `.../venv/resouces/images/`?  You double-checked the spelling etc.?

Comment: @kingsley oh god I feel stupid I misspelled the recourses... thx lmao

Comment: Heh! good bug found!